# Рак и раковина

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

У меня, может быть, глупый вопрос. Но подумалось, почему панцирь моллюсков называется раковина? Конечно, можно провести аналогию с панцирем рака, но какая все-таки связь? И, кстати, панцирь рака никогда раковиной не назывался.
А еще есть понятие раковистого скола у некоторых минералов.
Интересно было бы узнать, какое изначальное значение у этого слова и почему им называются достаточно отличные друг от друга вещи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раковина не имеет прямого отношения к "раку". 
Раковина - славянcкое "перламутр" от raky - оболочка. 
А рак (животное) -  праславянское rakъ.
Вряд ли родственны даже в ИЕ.

Answer (score 0):

. В санскрите есть слова **рак**шита – защита и **рак**шитар – защитник. И если учесть, что **кшат**рий –  воин,  ра**кшит**ар – защитник, а защитник это, как правило, защищающий что-либо воин, то можно сделать вывод о **ра**, как о слове, имеющем отношение к защите. Кто такой **рак**? – Это существо, защищённое панцирем, как и ракушка. **Раковина** – это предмет защиты моллюска. А есть ещё церковная **рака** – помещение для хранения мощей святых, либо гробница, как правило, в форме ковчега, с тем же назначением. Форма ковчега не случайна, ведь ковчег – защитное судно. И, наконец, есть бог солнца **Ра**, а к Богу чаще всего зачем обращаются? – За помощью и защитой. Вот такая связь между **раком** и **раковиной** выстроилась в моём сознании.